# Mutiple axios in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to use the useEffect with multiple axios request. Here is my code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState('');
const [popularCategories, setPopularCategories] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const result = await axios
            .get("http://example.com/api/v1/api1")
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });

        await setData(result.data);

        const resultCategories = await axios
        .get("http://example.com/api/v1/api2")
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        await setPopularCategories(resultCategories.data);
        
    })();
}, []);


return (
    <div>
        {data}
        {popularCategories}
    </div>
);
```

When I try to use them in return, it prints `data`, but not `popularCategories`. I couldn't understand why I can use data and not popularCategories I've checked three times that *http://example.com/api/v1/api2* returns a string.
Where am I missing?

Additional: This page is my index page. I've routed domain to directly here.

**EDIT**: true variable name is popularCategories. Problem still exists.

**EDIT 2**: I've realized that, when I remove the data and run only popular categories. The problem still exists. Would it be about API response time? Also, I've consol logged it. It print 4 times. First it doesn't give value first two print and it gives last two.

Comment: Typo: `resultCategories` -> `popularCategories`

Comment: you meant to use popularCategories in the return statement, as it's the one returned by useState, the resultCategories only exists within useEffect context

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski But I can use data. I'm setting state with setPopularCategories

Comment: @NikitaMadeev what do you mean?

Comment: @sundowatch Just replace `{resultCategories}` to `{popularCategories}` in return statement. Krzysztof Krzeszewski described the problem above.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question right now

Comment: @sundowatch problem still exists?

Comment: @sundowatch so what's the new issue?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've written wrong variable name for stackoverflow. Problem still exists

Comment: but you said to Nikita no, when he asked you if the problem still exists

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim sorry for my poor English, and a bit tired, I'm editing now

Comment: @NikitaMadeev yes

Comment: @sundowatch no worries

Comment: are you sure that APIs work?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes, checked 3 times. It may be something else. I've realized something and editing question

Comment: are you sure that `"http://example.com/api/v1/api2"` works?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes

Comment: what about trying the first url `"http://example.com/api/v1/api"` in the second request?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've edited my question. Could you check it please

Comment: i tried you code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customtablereact-forked-456sx?file=/src/App.js) with fake api and it works fine; please post the errors

Answer (score 1):

first of all, no sense to use await with setState - it does not return a promise, s awaiting them pointless.
Seems like you mess up with state name in you return:

```
return (
    <div>
        {data}
        {resultCategories} // should it be popularCategories ?
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I have checked you code with fake API and it works "as is" now when you changed return statement. As I already mentioned, there is no need to use await with setState. In addition, you can not wrap all the things inside useEffect with self-triggering async function - it will work fine with just useEffect(async()=>{...})

Answer (score 0):

I feel you need to specify the state object in second parameter. Looks like the dom is not rendering again when state changes.

Try below

```
const [data, setData] = useState('');
const [popularCategories, setPopularCategories] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const result = await axios
            .get("http://example.com/api/v1/api1")
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });

        await setData(result.data);

        const resultCategories = await axios
        .get("http://example.com/api/v1/api2")
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
        await setPopularCategories(resultCategories.data);
        
    })();
}, [data,popularCategories]); //specified this


return (
    <div>
        {data}
        {popularCategories}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: this will cause a infinite rendering since you set the dependencies in the useEffect

Comment: Yes @BoussadjraBrahim is right. it causes infinite rendering